# Custom android controls with elements

Tags: java, android, custom-controls

I have a pretty basic idea and experience with creating custom android controls.

I know I can create a custom control that is basically a layout with a number of controls in it, add attributes and any kind of logic I would want.

But now I need something a bit different. I have an app in which all of my `EditText` elements have a gray horizontal line under them. 
I know this can be achived with `backgroundTint` but this is only for api 21 and more.

So instead of adding this gray line below every `EditText` element I use, I would like to create a custom element that extends `EditText` but also has this gray line. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:src="@drawable/gray_divider"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in the code behind:

```
public class MyEditText extends LinearLayout {

public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Init();
}

private void Init() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_edit_text, this);

    InitViews(view);
}
```

So my problem is this:
In order for `MyEditText` to function like an `EditText` I have to create an attribute for every `EditText` attribute. I want to do this:

```
<MyEditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text_color="@android:color/white" />
```

Without adding anything in the code behind. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a good practice in this case, Use a background with bottom line.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:left="-10dp"
    android:right="-10dp"
    android:top="-10dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="@color/transparent"
            android:startColor="@color/transparent" />
        <stroke
            android:width="@dimen/border"
            android:color="@color/border" />
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/border" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Make a .xml resource and put it in Drawable folder.Eg border_bottom.xml

And for Edit text just give background like

```
    android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Works like charm! Very elegant as well. Changed the code a bit. `<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="-10dp"
        android:right="-10dp"
        android:top="-10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>`